# Why has mongo deprecated MongoIterable.forEach(Block)?

Tags: java, mongodb

`MongoIterable` has got two `forEach` methods on it:

```
Iterable.forEach(Consumer)
MongoIterable.forEach(Block)
```

In recent versions of the mongo java driver, `MongoIterable.forEach` has been deprecated, with a notice saying users should switch to `Iterable.forEach`.

However, the `MongoIterable.forEach` method is implemented in the main implementing class more-or-less like so:

```
try (MongoCursor<TResult> cursor = iterator()) {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        block.apply(cursor.next());
    }
}
```

and there is no corresponding override of `Iterable.forEach`. This means that `Iterable.forEach` leaks a `MongoCursor` that doesn't get closed, and so, if the deprecation comments are followed, loads of cursors are going to be leaked by changing to `Iterable.forEach`.

So why is `MongoIterable.forEach` marked as deprecated, when the replacement leaks a cursor object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3046, says the main reason for the change :

> The forEach(Block block) method on MongoIterable
>   conflicts with the default forEach method added to java.lang.Iterable
>   in Java 8. If you try to use either with a lambda expression you get a
>   compiler error which forces you to cast the lambda to either Block or
>   Consumer, which is not intuitive.
>
> The default forEach method in Iterable, though, is dangerous to use
>   with MongoIterable because it's not possible for it to force the
>   MongoCursor to be closed in the case where Consumer.accept throws an
>   exception, but in scope of JAVA-2010 we plan to address that. Given
>   that, it makes sense to deprecate MongoIterable#forEach(Block block) so that it can be removed in the next major release
>   and users will stop getting the compiler error.

Comment: Aah, I didn't spot `Iterable.forEach` has been overridden in all the specific implementations